# Cannot create a record in ZIP/postal Codes

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, axapta

I try to import 90 records from a .txt-file into a table in: Administration > Administration Area > Periodic > Data export/import > Definition Groups

I've made a new Definition Group, set the name and type (Custom) of it and Selected the Default file name.

In the Table setup I deleted all records and selected the table where I want to import the records, Import status = Import.

After clicking on the import-button in the Definition group-window I'm getting error-messages for every record and no data is imported:

> ERROR message sais: Cannot create a record in ZIP/postal Codes (CLIAddressZipCode).
>   ZIP/postal Code: , . The record already exists.

EXAMPLE OF A RECORD:

```
1440;Les Frèchaux;175557;BRAINE-LE-CHÂTEAU
```

The 1st field is the zipcode, the 2nd is the street, the 3rd is the ID, the 4th field is the city.

UPDATE:
I will try to add an if-statement: to check if the record already exists, if not the record will be inserted.

Comment: I do not trust this utility inside of AX. I find it too difficult to work with. I tend to save the file as a CSV and do the import by reading the file and inserting the data to the table through a job. I feel better when I have more control over the process. If you would like I could provide you with an example of the code to do this.

Comment: Googled this: http://www.dynamicscare.com/blog/index.php/commaio-for-flat-file-integrations

Comment: It was not me. I think someone else did, because you forgot to state a  question (which is why it was closed).

Comment: I did that after my previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for unique indexes in table `CLIAddressZipCode` (this is not a standard table).

This problem arises when your input contain two records which have the same values in the index fields.

The second record will throw the error when inserted saying: The record already exists.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a related table that it's inserting into and/or a blank '' record at the very beginning/end.  CLIAddressZipCode is custom.  Perhaps you're inserting into AddressZipCode, and there is code that will insert into CLIAddressZipCode or vice versa and one of those tables contains the duplicate data.

Comment: There is no blank record at the beginning nor the end of the file.

Comment: I meant a record with the unique key being blank.

Comment: You need a developer to look at it.  This shouldn't be too hard to figure out.  Just look for the unique index/key and you should check for what's duplicating.

Comment: The output was made by writing a SQL-query in a MS Access DataBase, then I exported the data that was generated by that query. To check if there are duplicates I used the "Find Duplicates Query Wizard" in Access and also tried to find them manually but can't find a single duplicate. The only solution is to ask a developer, I think.

Comment: It is a blank record that it is entering.  The " , " in the error message is where it would say what the record is.
"Code: , . The record already exists."

Answer (score 0):

Could the data be concatenated in some way?  eg 12345 is concatenated to 1234 which is the same as 1234.